# externally modified files in gvim

Tags: vim

if I have a file open in gvim and it get modified by an external program I end up with my buffer filled with this error and no possible escape but closing vim is there a good solution to this?

E813: Cannot close autocmd

using vim on linux if that matters.

BRG Anders Olme

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps reading `:help E813`, will help you find clues to your problem.

At the end it says:

> There is one situation where you get
>   the message while there is nothing
>   wrong: On a Win32 system on the day
>   daylight saving time starts.  There is
>   something in the Win32 libraries that
>   confuses Vim about the hour time
>   difference.  The problem goes away the
>   next day.

Is it possible this is you or has this problem been happening over a period of time?

My other thought is this is some autocmd gone awry which means something in your .vimrc or a plugin is messed up.  Try commenting out your .vimrc and running vim with `--noplugin` option and see if you can still recreate the problem

Comment: Get it on any files today it was the pom file that got updated via maven release plugin. Got a couple of plugins like nerdtree and such.. Maybe they are the cause.